# Xamarin.Forms - Loading Font from Shared Project

Tags: c#, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.forms, uwp

I've made a big library to use with all my Xamarin.Forms projects. This lib defines styles, shares reusable code fragments, and so on. Now because I use FontAwesome multiple times in different projects, I want to share the .ttf-File with the library.

Actually the font is stored in my UWPs `Assets/Fonts/` folder and is loaded like this:

```
<On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf#FontAwesome" />
```

This works quiet good, and no need to implement a custom rednerer (at least for UWP).
The Problem is that the Font does not seem to get loaded, when I define it as a `EmbeddedResource`, so I don't know how to load it from the library Project.

Maybe someone did such a thing ever before and could me tell the solution. Thanks!

## Edit:

I recreated a project, but I cannot load the Font-File without installing it on my Computer. You can download the Project here: https://github.com/DirtyNative/FATest

Answer (score 1):

To make the font usable, set its build action to `Content` and you can refer to it as:

```
FontFamily="ms-appx:///LibraryName/Path/To/Font.ttf#Name"
```

It seems UWP is unable to load embedded resources from XAML, or at least I haven't yet found a way which would work.

Comment: This works, thank you! The next problem i get is that if I say **Style="{StaticResource IconedRoundedEntryIconStyle}"** inside a View in my Shared Lib, I get an UnhandledException which does not show me any information. Also **DynamicResource** does not work

Comment: I would suggest closing this question as resolved and creating a new one, because it is a different problem. Just send me a link and I will check it out there :-)

Comment: ur totally right ;) Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669020/xamarin-forms-staticresource-in-shared-library

Comment: Thanks :-). I will check it out as soon as I get to my PC in an hour or so

Comment: I was too fast with marking as asnwered. Somehow this worked because the Project was not deployed correctly and ran as an old version which worked. I did another try, and your line does not work

Comment: Have you set the font as Content and its action to copy always or Copy if newer? I didn't mention the second part in my answer so that might be the problem

Comment: Yes I did, I have set it as Copy always

Comment: That is very unusual. Could you open the `bin` folder and try to locate the font file there? Is it in the LibraryName folder?

Comment: Yes it is there, located under "Assets\Fonts\Fontname.ttf"

Comment: If it is not too big trouble - could you please create a very simple GitHub repo with just an UWP project and font file in the same location as in your solution, so I could try it out and see where the problem is? I truly don't know at this point, as it does work on my side...

Comment: Alright, I try to recreate a project structure and upload it to Github