# Xamarin.Forms - StaticResource in Shared Library

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

I've made a Shared Library Project which defines some often used Views. For example:

```
<Label x:Name="lblIcon"
    FontSize="30" 
    Margin="20,0,5,0"
    WidthRequest="30"
    VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

Now to reuse that style, I defined that style inside App.Xaml (still inside the shared Project) and want to reference it via StaticResource:

```
<Label x:Name="lblIcon"
    Style="{StaticResource TheLabelsStyle}"
    VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

But this throws an UnhandledException with no further information.

Hopefully someone sees my mistakes and could help me. Thanks in advance!

## Edit1

Here is the Style:

```
<Style x:Key="TheLabelsStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

## Edit 2

After cleaning and rebuilding the solution multiple times, I figured out the issue comes from the merged Dictionary, especially the FontFamilies.

```
<!-- App.xaml inside the Shared Project -->
<Application.Resources>

    <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <styles:FontFamilies />
            <styles:LabelStyles />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The LabelStyles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:styles="clr-namespace:SharpLibrary.Forms.Source.Styles;assembly=SharpLibrary.Forms"
         x:Class="SharpLibrary.Forms.Source.Styles.LabelStyles">

<Style x:Key="HeaderLabel" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="IconedRoundedEntryIconStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource FontAwesome}" />
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The FontFamilies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SharpLibrary.Forms.Source.Styles.FontFamilies">

<OnPlatform x:Key="FontAwesome" x:TypeArguments="x:String" >
    <OnPlatform.Platforms>
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome"/>
        <On Platform="UWP" Value="ms-appx:///SharpLibrary.Forms/Assets/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf#FontAwesome"/>
    </OnPlatform.Platforms>
</OnPlatform>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

But if I do something like...

```
<Label x:Name="lblIcon"
    FontSize="30" 
    FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontAwesome}"
    Margin="20,0,5,0"
    WidthRequest="30"
    VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

... this works

Comment: Can you add the markup for your style, please?

Comment: If your style definition is exactly as you posted, try changing the Key from `TheLabelsSytle` to `TheLabelsStyle` :) Typos are the worst in XAML.

Comment: Ups sorry, this was just a mistake i made when writing it here xD For sure the Styles name is an other, and everything is spelled correctly

Comment: Well, barring the typo, the code you posted is absolutely correct. So you're saying the label works without the style but throws an exception if you change the label to use the style? If so, could you expand the code to include the whole `Application.Resources` section? Also, sometimes Android projects go funny, so a clean & rebuild may help.

Comment: I pasted some more code and found some more details about this issue, maybe this helps solving it

Comment: Do you mean that if you use DynamicResource in the binding for the FontFamily it works, but if you use StaticResource it doesn't?